# what is the math for gravity causing different kinds of orbit ( ellipse, parabola ,straight line ) for an object in different cases?

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry, algebra-precalculus, projectile-motion, celestial-mechanics

**case-1:**
    the motion or you can say the orbit of a projectile is `parabolic` because gravity acts on it.
       [image]

**case-2:**
the motion or the orbit of an object thrown straight up ( *at less than the escape velocity*) or thrown straight down is a `straight line`
    [image]

**case-3:**

then we have the planetary motion which is `elliptical` and of course it is because of the gravity
     [image]

now I am going to the point,
the general formula of gravitational force is,
    $$F=\frac{G\cdot m_1 \cdot m_2}{r^2}$$

> now, how would you derive the equation of the parabola, straight line and ellipse from the general formula of gravity for the given cases.

I also want to know other types of orbit and the algebraic equation for that orbits motion.

Comment: The derivation of the [orbit equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orbit_equation) is quite involved (typically an entire hour-long lecture), so this isn't a very suitable MSE question.

Comment: Actually your questions 1 and 3 do not have the same model of gravity. In the first case we get a parabola because the ground is "flat" (which is a good model when short distances are involved, like cannon balls and such). In the third case, the ground is more like a point (for instance the center of gravity of the Eearth), and the equations are more complex but more precise. They admit of all types of conic equations as solution, depending I believe on the initial conditions on position and velocity.

Comment: @Bungo sir, without the answers to these questions I can`t proceed to further study. Can you suggest some research paper; books; videos where I can get the answer to this question?

Comment: @imsteffen sir, thank you for the information . but I need a mathematical visualization, would you mind?

Comment: Here's a detailed mathematical exposition: http://web.physics.ucsb.edu/~fratus/phys103/LN/TBP.pdf

Comment: @Aretino Very helpful indeed!